# Scrolling through autocomplete results in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

In Jupyter notebook, when pressing Tab to bring up the autocomplete options, I find it cumbersome to use the up and down arrow keys on a mac to scroll through the list. I was wondering if there is any way of doing this (possibly by changing some configuration file) by using "Ctrl" + "P" and "Ctrl" + "n"?

I would appreciate any suggestions! Thanks.

Comment: Does repeated Tab scroll down?

Comment: @hpaulj no unfortunately it doesn't

Comment: You use a notebook in a browser, so the browser has first say on how the ctrls are used.  In my Linux chrome ^p is print and ^n window. You might have to use a browser extension to change the key shortcuts.

Comment: I wonder more how to turn that back into ipython's behavior, because I hate the scrolling menu.  Google brought me here, and I fear my search will ultimately be futile.  Free Software and docs, still a sore point in 2018.

Comment: @SiavoshMahboubian did you solve this by any chance?